# Forces: why are the theta's equal?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, friction

I found this figure in my physics book, the task says that the incline got a angle of theta. How do figure out that the gravity and the y-axis got the same angle as the incline? There is no explanation of this in the chapter of the book.

[image: Theta]

Comment: You can explore the equivalence of triangles or just start writing down the angles (like the one between the slope and the $m\vec{g}$ arrow). It boils down to geometry, it's not physics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This drawing might help...[image]

Its really just playing around with right angled triangles